# How to name a foreign key different from db name in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way in mongoose + Node.js/Express to define the relation between the foreign key field and what I refer to that field in the model is? My issue is that I have a mongo database where my foreign keys are all formatted like 'exampleId' instead of 'example'. I could just call out 'exampleId' directly but then it leads to weird things like when I populate 'exampleId' instead of 'example' (which is confusing because once populated, it is now the 'example' itself instead of its id).

Here is how I do it now and it works with my graphQL server, but only if my field in the database is 'course' while my database's field is 'courseId'

```
const CourseSchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: String },
  sections: [{
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    ref: 'Section'
  }],
});


const SectionType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'SectionType',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    courseId: {
      type: require('./course_type'),
      resolve(parentValue) {
        return Section.findById(parentValue)
          .populate('course')
          .then(section => section.course);
      }
    },
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! With the newest version of mongoose, you actually can use virtual fields to accomplish what I wanted to do and this technique allows for flexibility in laying out your schema. Say that my MongoDB collections look like the following:

```
Courses { _id, sectionIds }
Lectures { _id, courseId }
```

I can use the following schema in mongoose and it will allow me to refer to `course.lectures` or `lecture.course` instead of the usual `course.lectureIds` or `section.courseId`:

```
const CourseSchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: String },
});

CourseSchema.virtual('sections', {
  type: Schema.Types.String,
  ref: 'Section',
  localField: 'sectionIds',
  foreignField: '_id',
  justOne: false,
});

CourseSchema.statics.findSections = function(id) {
  return this.findById(id)
    .populate('sections')
    .then(course => course.sections);
}


const SectionSchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: String },
});

SectionSchema.virtual('course', {
  type: Schema.Types.String,
  ref: 'Course',
  localField: 'courseId',
  foreignField: '_id',
  justOne: true,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually MongoDB isn't a relational database. You can alter the field and its name whatever you like. Ex I Have an Owner(Meteor.users) table and Patient Table with this column

```
ownerid : {type: String, min: 1},
firstname: {type: String, min: 1},
lastname: {type: String, min: 1},
middlename: {type: String, min: 1, optional: true},
createdbyid: { type: String },
createdbyname: { type: String },
createdat: { type: Date, defaultValue: new Date() },
updatedbyid: { type: String, optional: true },
updatedbyname : { type: String, optional: true },
updatedat: { type: Date, defaultValue: new Date() },
```

I can easily stamp the value of my {Meteor.Users()._id} to ownerid of my designated patient by just processing them at meteor.methods. You don't have to worry about foreign keys mongo doesn't do relational databases you can customize your database whatever you like. I Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am not sure if this answers my question. I am using the mongoose package to interact with my mongoDB and it is making some assumptions about which fields to look at in the DB to find a value that don't turn out to be true. Also, I can't tell how you are changing the value of your field in the examples that you put there. I can't see  a property like 'name' or something that would say that 'updatedbyid' is actually 'updatedBy' in the DB for example.

Answer (score 0):

[Mongoose Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) posits that _id has to be used in refs and that`[i]t is important to match the type of _id to the type of ref.` , e.g.:

```
var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number, //it is `Number`
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String,
  fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }] // use `Number` to match
});
```

I also wonder if by 'database' you mean 'collection'.